# Can you help me with an issue with the Test Results Report tool in Azure DevOps?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, reporting

Test Results Report:

The issue is that it's failing to generate a report when there's over 300 test cases in a test suite, when around 1.5k test cases was the limit.  I've also observed that after it successfully generated a report for a test suite that have less than 300 test cases, if I select another test suite that also have less than 300 test cases, it will fail to generate the report.

I opened up the browser console and saw a bunch of error occurs when it failed to generate the report:

See attachment

The report is not generating isn't because I didn't wait long enough.  I waited over 20 minutes for it to generate a report for a test suite with a little over 300 test cases and it still failed.  Back then when it was working, it took at most 5 minutes to generate a report for a test suite with over 1k test cases.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kLIV.jpg)

I waited over 20 minutes for it to generate a report for a test suite with a little over 300 test cases and it still failed.  Back then when it was working, it took at most 5 minutes to generate a report for a test suite with over 1k test cases.